# Processing raw data strings from a text file into a CSV file

Tags: php, file, csv, text

I have a text file full of hundreds of lines of raw data. The data has no specific form of separation, but I know what each part refers to. For example:

```
316smithjohn112007
```

316 is the ID of that user,
smith is the surname,
john is the forename,
11 is the floor,
and 2007 is the extension number.

What I now need to do is pull all that data into one CSV file, with the correct columns and the data separate. It needs to be a PHP script which I can run whenever an updated CSV is needed.

So for example:

```
ID,surname,forename,floor,ext
316,smith,john,11,2007
```

Hoping someone can help.

Comment: Read up on basic string manipulation with PHP then post what you try and we can help then.  Right now your question is too broad and it seems you have not tried anything.

Comment: Can you use other Unix tools (sed, awk)?

Comment: that's some serious machine learning there :) Not sure how you're going to get a PHP script to separate smith from john.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a loop for each line and try to figure out what you should do. You could split the Numbers but not the names. PHP dont know what are first and lastnames.